Accepted answer with bounty deleted
my question Does Independence Imply Conditional Independence in regression? which had a 50pts bounty earlier had an accepted answer with the bounty pointe assigned to the contributor. The answer was deleted most likely due to user suspension! I would like to get that answer back as it was quite useful. Can someone help reinstating the answer?

The user was Raynard Bond

It is possible the user was a sock puppet posting answers generated by AI (without attribution) that look good on the surface, but aren't ultimately quite correct.  There has been a lot of that lately.

The answer was reinstated, thanks a lot!

As gung - Reinstate Monica noted,  there has been a rise recently in posts written using AI by sock puppet accounts throughout many SE communities. See a Meta post for more detail.
The initial deletion was owing to the lack of attributing the usage of gen AIs in composing the answer, which amounts to plagiarism.
Problems with such answers are that even though they look sleek and sound at a glance, chances are that they are gibberish and at best a hodge-podge of unnecessary concepts and recapitulation of what was already said or speculated in the question, albeit in an otherwise authoritative language.
The answer has been undeleted now. But please take it with a pinch of salt. Already other veteran users have guided you, but  tread with caution.
